# Error while looping through a list and adding values based on a condition into a different list - Python/JSON

Tags: python, json, list, loops, ordereddictionary

```
from collections import OrderedDict


allReqs = getReqs(searchQuest, emptyList)  
toDoList = []
for x in allReqs:
    questData = next((i for i in response.json()['quests'] if i['title']== allReqs[allReqs.index(x)]),None)
    data = OrderedDict()
    for key in ('title','status','difficulty','members','questPoints','userEligible'):
        data[key] = questData.get(key,'')
    #print(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
    #print(data['status'])
    if data['status'] == "NOT_COMPLETED":
        toDoList.append(data['title'] + "REDDD")
    elif data['status'] == "COMPLETED":
        toDoList.append(data['title'] + "GREENNN")
    else:
        print("something broke")
```

> ERROR MESSAGE:
>       ['Diamond in the RoughGREENNN']
>       ['Diamond in the RoughGREENNN', 'Stolen HeartsGREENNN']
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "questing.py", line 58, in 
>       data[key] = questData.get(key,'')
>       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Any ideas how to fix this? I can post more code if needed.
I am trying to search through a list of names, check them against the `json` response and if their `'title'` is found, check the `'status'` and depending on the value of the `'status'` append them into another list that will be printed at the end.

Thanks!

Comment: Either your key(one of your keys) spelling is wrong or the key is not present.

Comment: Looks like questData is empty.